# R Floop behavior

Tags: r, loops

Suppose I have the following R loop:

```
for(i in 1:5){
print(i)
i = i + 1
}
```

This produces the following result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Which is weird since I did redefine the index inside the loop.

Why do we see this behavior?

I thought I would see something like the following:

```
1
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: This one indeed produces ```1 2 3 4 5```. Please check again.

Comment: See the edits I made.

Comment: Yes, seems like you are looking for `while` loop instead of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment to the looping variable `i` is discarded on the next loop iteration, so `i = i + 1` has no effect. If you want to change the value of `i` within the loop, you can use a `while` loop.

However, your intended output of `1 3 4 5 6` doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons:

- assignment of `i`, as already mentioned;
- why does it not increment every other loop?; and
- the domain of `i`, `1:5`, is locked in at the first pass of the loop.

Having said that, try this:

```r
i <- 1
lim <- 5
while (i <= lim) {
  if (i == 2) {
    lim <- lim + 1
  } else {
    print(i)
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
# [1] 1
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
# [1] 5
# [1] 6
```

(My only caution here is that if your increment of `i` is conditional on anything, there needs to be something else that prevents this from being an infinite loop. Perhaps this caution is unnecessary in your use-case, but it seems relevant to at least mention it.)

Answer (score 0):

The `i` is the for each value and  that cannot be modified with `i  = i + 1`.  We may use an `if` condition

```
for(i in 1:5){
if(i != 2)
  print(i)
}
```

-output

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

---

Also, if the intention is to subset a vector, why not use vectorized option

```
v1 <- 1:5
v1[v1 != 2]
```